# Use /etc/aliases for outgoing mail relayed by postfix with local domain

Tags: 12.04, cron, postfix

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with postfix configured as satellite system that relays outgoing mail to Gmail. For sake of example, my registered domain is example.com I want root cronjobs' error output to be mailed to my real david@example.com inbox. I have this relay working correctly.

But these root cronjobs are set by default to email to root@example.com which isn't a real email address. I have in my `/etc/aliases`:

```
root: david@example.com
```

example.com isn't listed in postfix's main.cf's `mydestination` so postfix doesn't think this mail is local. It bypasses processing via `/etc/aliases` and tries to send to root@example.com.

A workaround is adding `MAILTO=david` at the top of each cron file. But there are many. Another workaround is to setup root@example.com as a real inbox that forwards to david@example.com. Is there a better way? I.e. is there a way to relay emails that have local domains but still process their addressee with `/etc/aliases`?

Answer (score 6):

I guess you could use a virtual alias.

If example.com is your domain on postfix:

in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

in `/etc/postfix/virtual`

```
root@example.com    dave
```

after editing

```
postmap hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

It should be working.

If I understood your question correctly, emails to root@example.com will now go to local user dave.

Comment: This works for Centos 6 :) Thx

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use the `recipient_canonical_maps` configuration parameter of postfix. Compared to the `virtual_alias_maps`, the advantage is that `myorigin` neither needs to be in `mydestination` nor in `virtual_mailbox_maps` (which `virtual_alias_domains` defaults to). Thus, this postfix instance does *not* become the final destination for `myorigin`.

Add this to your `main.cf`:

```
recipient_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical
```

Then create a file named `/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical` and enter something like this:

```
root@example.com david@example.com
```

Finally hash it.

```
# postmap /etc/postfix/recipient_canonical
```

Answer (score 1):

if david is also a local account, then you could have the alias line be local-only, and then set up the david account to do the forwarding.  /etc/aliases would be:

```
root: david
```

You could then use other postfix rules or a .forward file on the david account to get the mail to gmail.

Comment: This is not working with relaying...