# Why does /usr/bin/mail ignore aliases in $HOME/.mailrc

Tags: email, postfix, mailutils

When I send email using /usr/bin/mail on the command line (Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit), it does not pay attention to any aliases in my .mailrc file. Does anybody know how to fix this?

To reproduce the problem:

1. Put an alias in $HOME/.mailrc

   alias foo me@whatever.com
2. Try to mail the alias:

   $ echo hello | /usr/bin/mail -s testing foo
3. Read /var/log/mail.log and see "foo" bounce as an unknown user:

   Sep 7 11:15:39 mycomputer postfix/local[9707]: EE038F6028B: to=<foo@mycomputer.mydomain>, relay=local, delay=0.1, delays=0.07/0/0/0.03, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "foo")

However, my other mail programs, such as Emacs VM, respect the aliases in $HOME/.mailrc.

This didn't used to happen in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, my previous system.

On further investigation... I ran:

```
$ mail -f mymailbox
? alias foo
foo        me@whatever.com
```

So /usr/bin/mail is indeed processing $HOME/.mailrc, but somehow, even though "mail" knows the alias "foo", the result is that postfix sees an email message to "foo@mycomputer.mydomain" instead of the alias expansion. I don't know who's misconfigured: mail (GNU mailutils) or postfix.

Comment: Have you tried using mailx instead?

Comment: On my system, /usr/bin/mailx and /usr/bin/mail are both symlinks to the same executable, /usr/bin/mail.mailutils. So I get the same behavior.

Comment: So, I installed the Ubuntu package "bsd-mailx", which provides a real mailx. The problem does not occur! Alias "foo" expands properly so the mail is sent to me@whatever.com.

Answer (score 3):

I did:

```
sudo apt-get install bsd-mailx
```

and the problem went away. The mail programs provided by bsd-mailx support .mailrc aliases, while apparently the ones in mailutils do not.

Credit to mdpc (https://askubuntu.com/users/5863/mdpc) for leading me to this solution in his comment above.

Answer (score 2):

From my recollection....the mail program is a bare bones local mail delivery agent and is generally called from programs such as sendmail.  I have found that the mailx program is the more user friendly program that has a lot more whistles and bells.  If I recall mailx is available and can be used on nearly all Linux/UNIX systems.

I got into the habit of using mailx over mail way back in the Solaris days.

Answer (score 2):

So `bsd-mailx` may not have this problem; but, it also has a lot fewer features than gnu `mailutils`.

I also ran into this problem recently on a new Ubuntu install; but, discovered that the following in my `~/.mailrc` fixed the problem:

```
set inplacealiases
```

That's it. Aliases worked after I did that.

Answer (score -1):

After you have installed the mail server using something like `sudo apt-get install mailutils` and created the aliases file, you need to let the system read and create a hash file of the aliases configuration.

```
sudo newaliases
```

Changing the `aliases` file without running the above command afterwards will not make any changes for the system.

This [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244452/use-etc-aliases-for-outgoing-mail-relayed-by-postfix-with-local-domain) might be relevant to your question.

Comment: That may be true for a system-wide aliases file, but not for $HOME/.mailrc.